# Question about if manipulating is Taylor series justified?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have a few doubts about Taylor series expansions, and how you can manipulate to get power series expansion for new functions.

For example I know  the power series expansion for $\log(x)$, about $1$ can I get the power series expansion for $\log(x)/x$ by just dividing each term by $x$, I feel like I can do it, but I am not sure if it is justified.

Also I do know that two power series can be multiplied, on their common intersection of radius of convergence, so does it mean we can multiply individual terms of a power series expansion of $f(x)$ by $x^k$ and then obtain the power series for $xf(x)$?

Thank You

Comment: The series expansion that you have for $\ln(x)$ is not going to be of powers of $x$, therefore dividing by $x$ is going to spoil its original powers. Pursuing your intention, you could expand $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x_0}\frac{1}{1+(x-x_0)/x_0}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(x-x_0)^n/x_0^n$, where $x_0$ is the center of the series that you have for $\ln(x)$, and then multiply this series by the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Say, $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}$ for $|x|<r$. For each fixed $x\ne 0$, $|x|<r$, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}$ is about a series of numbers with partial sums $S_{n}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k+1}$ and we have $S_{n}(x)/x=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}$.

Now $S_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ so $S_{n}(x)/x\rightarrow f(x)/x$ and hence $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}$ exists and is $f(x)/x$.

For the multiplication of two power series, consider the partial sums and argue in the similar way.

Comment: The problem is that, in their case, they don't have that $\ln(x)=f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$. So, they can't even start.

Comment: I was answering the general question not the specific example that OP has indicated, I hope OP will get some details from my answer. Anyway, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: And I guess OP was trying to say $\ln(1+x)$ rather than $\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I was actually thinking about $ln(x)$ about 1 but just realized that then it wouldn't make sense anyway to divide by $x$ to find the series expansion about 1

Comment: @user68099 You can multiply by the series of $1/x$ about $1$, by expanding $1/x=1/(1+x-1)=\sum_n (-1)^n(x-1)^n$.